# R purrr system2 map

Tags: r, purrr, system2

I have a vector of filenames A and I have an equivalent vector of new names for those files -- B.

I was hoping to do:

```
test <-map2(A, B, ~system2('mv', args=c(.x, .y)))
```

or perhaps

```
test <-map2(A, B, ~system2('mv', args=paste(.x, .y)))
```

but .x and .y don't get interpreted nicely and the command fails.

> mv: cannot stat
>   '/home/rob/KRBD_Data/Client_ID/000/raw/monthzips/2015-01/Data_2015-01-07.zip'

If I use rename as the command I get

```
test <-map2(A, B, ~system2('rename', args=paste(.x, .y)))
```

> Unknown regexp modifier "/r" at (user-supplied code), at end of line
>
> Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at (user-supplied code), at end of line

Answer (score 0):

If you paste together the arguments, the `system2` function will escape that space that separates them, as though it's one long filename that contains a space.

Instead, pass both the arguments as a vector:

```
test <-map2(A, B, ~system2('mv', args=c(.x, .y)))
```

Comment: That worked.  In fact I was distracted by one missing file, it had been working for a few iterations. Dah! Thank you!